# How could pirates reasonably transport dinosaurs in captivity, some of them enormous, across oceans?

Tags: transportation, dinosaurs, trade, sea

In my novel, there is money to made in the capturing and selling of 'exotic' animals from a distant, jungle-covered continent, though for various reasons (notably that it is illegal under Roman rule) buyers often like to keep their purchases and contacts secret. So they hire pirates who sail to these strange lands and capture the unusual animals found there. However, often these animals can be quite enormous (e.g T-rex like creatures, giant anacondas etc) and dangerous.

Obviously the hunters would have to have some kind of tranquilizing methods consistent with a voyage at sea taking potentially days. 
Issues would include how to get the animal on board, how and where too keep the animal, how to keep it sedated, methods for preventing disaster if sedation failed, and importantly, how to keep it alive.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: very relevant story. https://www.outsideonline.com/2086576/how-5-ton-african-elephant-crosses-ocean

Comment: What is the level of technology? There were pirates in the bronze age, there were pirates with 18th century tall ships, and there are pirates now with speedboats and AK-47s. You mention Roman rule, so is the level of technology roughly late antiqiuty?

Comment: Ixalan 2: Electric Boogaloo

Comment: can someone who is hired to capture animals really be called a "pirate"?

Comment: Yes, roughly. I mentioned Roman rule to convey the technology level in the novel. The 'Romans' aren't actually Roman as this isn't an alternate history, but they are probably most similar to my ruling nation. If I'm honest I still need to do a good bit of research on naval capabilities of those times but for the sake of  the story let assume the shipbuilding has progressed a great deal faster than it did in our world so we do have ships that can reliably cross oceans (though not without risk)

Comment: @ths, if they capture animals from the vessels of others, they can

Comment: @user28434 or if the animals make and sail their own vessels, on which they are captured. :-)

Comment: @Mahab describing the persons who capture exotic animal s alive and transport them by sea as "pirates" is inaccurate.   Pirates are evil criminals who attack ships and sell the goods they steal for profit.  The main crime your animal transporters commit seems to be smuggling forbidden goods, which is much less evil than piracy.  So if the characters who smuggle exotic animals are merely smugglers and not pirates they will be much less evil.

Comment: @M.A.Golding You make a good point there. It wasn't really relevant to the question so I didn't explain, but the pirates are not solely smugglers for the most part. In my mind, they aren't all evil. Sure, there are some very bad people in there, but really its a hodgepodge mix of traditonal 'pirates', outlaws, escaped slaves, free people in search of fortune, and of course - smugglers. The dinosaur thing isn't what defines them. In fact, the majority of them aren't into it or don't know about it. Generally its the people buying these creatures that are more on the evil end of the spectrum.

Comment: @M.A.Golding They aren't just smugglers, they're poachers. Poaching is taken very seriously in some places (to the point of "shoot on sight" policies in some nature reserves), as it often results in significant decreases of the population of endangered species in their native areas.

Comment: May I advice you try  ARK. At first you will try to Punch the Dinos, then you will discover how easy it is to steal eggs. You will soon craft narcos to drug them and nest to bring them down.

Comment: If Hannibal could get elephants (a warm-blooded mammal) to Europe (which presumably he did at the straight of Gibraltar), dinosaurs should be a cinch. I'd assume the dinosaurs were cold-blooded and put them in the hold with lots of ice. Then let the ice melt and see all hell break loose.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

**In eggs**

As in, a fertile dinosaur egg, not the adult. Moving livestock is always tricky, even more so when said livestock is composed of strong and dangerous creatures, which have a tendency to die easily in the wrong temperature, thanks to the fact that they're cold-blooded.

If pirates wanted to smuggle these creatures from their distant territories back to these lands, they'd kill the parents and steal the eggs (or just steal the eggs and run like crazy), then ferry the eggs back, and sell them for a tidy profit. Of course, you'd have to prove that it's a bona fide dino egg, so perhaps the pirates would let them hatch into baby dinos on the far side of the ocean, but the easiest way to smuggle a massive T-rex is to just steal a T-rex egg and take it across the ocean like that.

Comment: Nothing like a good sensible answer. Although egg smuggling may have one disadvantage. Travel time may be longer than gestation time inside the eggs. The care & feeding baby tyrannosaurs may not be as troublesome as catering for the adults, but not without its problems. Plus one for commonsense.

Comment: Dinosaurs matured relatively slowly, it took them many years to reach their adult size.

Comment: I should be mentioned that whether dinosaurs were cold- or warm-blooded is an active debate in the scientific community: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physiology_of_dinosaurs#Metabolic_options

Comment: Regarding the proof: Wouldn't the egg be large enough to be recognizable?

Comment: @MatthieuM. sure, but some sneaky people would just made a fake egg and sell it for them shiny doubloons.

Comment: @infinitezero: If one cannot tell the difference between an egg and a rock, one may not be able to tell the difference between a chicken and a dinosaur, so...

Comment: I said a fake and not a rock. Certainly you can do better than just picking up a rock and say it's an egg. Second of all, if you've never seen a dinosaur egg before, you might be suspicious before buying one for a large a mount of money (and rightly so). Other species might have big eggs but are not dinosaurs (or not the dinosaur you want?). There are multiple reasons why you might want proof.

Comment: +1 many animals learn a lot about behavior and how to interact from their mothers. By never giving them the chance to even meet the mother, this would be a great explanation for why pirated Dino's tend to be a little "less stable" than their wild counterparts. Depending on what OP has in store for them, this could be interesting.

Comment: @infinitezero they can carry the skull of the t-rex or some claws as a proof, also most of the illegal commerce is trusted base, because no laws are supporting it.

Comment: But if the dinosaurs (and snakes that OP included) are like our snakes, they lay their eggs and abandon them.  The pirates follow one about to lay and get the eggs fresh for the longest time till hatching.  How many pirates will it take to make the species extinct in ten years?

Comment: @WGroleau I dont think pirates will be worried about animal extinction or climate change.

Comment: @ErickSilva, no, but the author of the story might be concerned about the species lasting.  And no one till now said anything about climate change.

Comment: As my grandfather once told me, "You don't have to outrun the bear - you just have to outrun the guy next to you". Poor Gramps - he never was much of a runner...

Comment: OP asked how to transport a dinosaur, when they should have asked how they could avoid transporting a dinosaur!

Comment: @WGroleau They also won't be extinct, unless they all die after being transported, which makes the transport kinda pointless.

Comment: Noah already did this (Genesis 6-8).

Comment: @infinitezero it’s possible to use a technique called Candling to see what is inside an egg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candling It has been done for centuries.

Comment: That only works if the shell is not too opaque. Which might not be the case for dinosaur eggs.

Comment: @infinitezero, scam auction may exist sure. That doesn't change the fact that if anyone make that kind of statement in public or private actioun there is only 2 possibility. Either it's a mad man and no one actually buying cares. Or he just trying to get a lower price. You do not to publicly accuse the seller to be a thief, the buyer to be dumber than rock, the auctioneer and place owner to be thief dumb or complice.

Answer (score 14):

There are a number of questions here, let's take them one at a time.

## How to capture / sedate the animal, and keep it alive?

Through its food, what the pirates need is some plant or drug that will keep the animal unconscious. This should be used in it's capture, just prepare a big pile of meat or other food with some of the knockout plant inside. The animal eats it, then falls unconscious. The pirates will need to periodically feed/drug the animal during transit. This can be accomplished with a feeding tube and a way to grind up the food and knockout plant.

## How to get the animal on board?

You don't put it on board the ship, rather on a floating barge specifically designed for that purpose. The barge will be towed by the ship. With effort (or beasts of burden) the same barge can be dragged across land to load the beasts, then to a beach suitable for launching the barge.

## Where to keep the animal?

It remains lashed down on the barge for the entire trip.

## How to prevent disaster?

Provided the animal cannot swim faster than they can sail their ship, all they need to do is cut the tow line to the barge and leave. The longer the line the more safe they'll be.

Comment: So the animal will be exposed to the elements for the whole cruise ... he'd better be really cold and water resistant to survive a 3 weeks transatlantic passage.

Comment: @Hoki I guess you'd put appropriate covers on the barge to keep your animal alive. The "barge" doesn't have to be just a flat-bed transporter (although it could be for shorter-distance or fair-weather transport).

Comment: Real-life animal smugglers are notorious for inhumane treatment of their cargo and tolerance of less-than-100% survival rates of even very valuable animals. A system with a 60% chance of bare survival would probably be considered just fine.

Comment: @Hoki Perhaps much like today's reptiles' cold blooded nature, towing them in the cold could keep them dormant.  Would require a plot device to keep it the perfect temp to not kill them and keep them cool until arrival.

Answer (score 12):

**Arr, sail north.**

Some modern lizards hibernate when it gets cold.

On the other hand, evidence seems to suggest that dinosaurs probably didn't hibernate.

It may be within the scope of your readers' suspension of disbelief to just accept this in the context of your book about dinosaur-smuggling pirates.

Answer (score 7):

**Feed it so it sleeps.**

- Obviously the hunters would have to have some kind of tranquilizing methods consistent with a voyage at sea taking potentially days.

Many reptiles enter into a long period of inactivity after gorging themselves.

- Issues would include how to get the animal onboard:

Place bait trail and after it crosses the ramp, lift it. Maybe the animal can't swim and won't leave the ship from fear of drowning.

- How and where to keep the animal

Get a whole ship for it, place ropes or chains and drag it. So there is no fear of TRex munching the crew.

- how to keep it sedated, methods for preventing disaster if sedation failed

Count on placing a bunch of herbs inside the guts of a dead cow. T. Rex eats the cow and besides falling into the common hibernation, you will also get the bonus of the sedatives.

- importantly, how to keep it alive.

You will lose some to dehydration/drowning/storms. As long as you get a HIGH sum to make it worthwhile, your pirates won't care.

Answer (score 4):

Transport Juveniles.

A fully grown adult dinosaur would require an independent barge as other answers have suggested.  An adult dinosaur would need to be kept sedated through their food or water.  In addition, they would require significant care to ensure it's survival in their sedated state and protection from the elements while at sea.

It would become easier if you are transporting juveniles instead.  They can be kept in iron cages on the main ship instead.  They would require less food and management than an adult.

Answer (score 2):

As a pirate, I know I'm going to need a large ship. It's going to be so ridiculously large, I have no doubt Caesar will outlaw such craft to prevent the smuggle of dinosaurs. So I can't keep it in Rome, or the Mediterranean at all. I'll have to store her in Gaul, where the Empire's influence is weaker.

I shall then sail directly to the new world. Once there, I will incapacitate the creatures with venom derived from snakes. Hauling these beasts onto my ship will be difficult, but they are valuable enough to keep enough hands on board to do the job. I'll store them in the center of my massive ship, chained up, periodically injecting them below the midsection with a paralyzing agent (also derived from snake venom) to prevent their thrashing about.

I will then sail due North, making landfall every night, heading as close to the ice as I dare. When I approach [modern day Greenland], I shall stock up on supplies to feed the beast for the voyage East to Britannia. Landing in Britannia, I shall again stock up on supplies to sail the relatively short distance to Gaul. I shall off-load the beast there, and make the journey on foot into the Empire.

Larger beasts will not eat me or my crew, provided they are well fed, humans are too small to be worth the effort. Mid-sized beasts may very well make the attempt, so it is best to keep them heavily sedated.

The long necked beasts are worth the effort only once a season, as they fetch a fine price, but can only be taken one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

**À la Gulliver's?**

In Jonathan Swift's novel, when Gulliver travels to Lilliput, he finds himself tied down and held by several ropes onto the land.

A dinosaur could have been sedated and tied on top of a structure, that would later be used as a raft?

The raft then would be towed by ships, which would keep the crew safe, short of the chosen sailors who have to go check on the creature once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Assume they are cold-blooded. Cold-blooded reptiles are [poikilotherms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poikilotherm) and torpid if not exposed to a source of heat. They need to bask in sunshine or sit in a warm place in order to raise their body temperature. You can play around with a cold gators mouth and it won't do more than give you an angry stare. So, if you assume that the dinosaurs were cold-blooded (which they apparently weren't) then the problem amounts to keeping them cool, say in the ships hold, refrigerated with some salted ice.

If Hannibal managed to get [voracious](https://www.nytimes.com/1984/09/18/science/the-mystery-of-hannibal-s-elephants.html) elephants to Italy from northern Africa, then bringing over a few dinos should be a breeze.